# I ain't no Fortunate sum

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, primes, integer-partitions

The primorial \$p_n\#\$ is the product of the first \$n\$ primes. The sequence begins \$2, 6, 30, 210, 2310\$.

A [Fortunate number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortunate_number), \$F_n\$, is the smallest integer \$m > 1\$ such that \$p_n\# + m\$ is prime. For example \$F_7 = 19\$ as:

$$p_7\# = 2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13\times17 = 510510$$

Adding each number between \$2\$ and \$18\$ to \$510510\$ all yield composite numbers. However, \$510510 + 19 = 510529\$ which is prime.

The Fortunate numbers below \$200\$ are

$$3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 23, 37, 47, 59, 61, 67, 71, 79, 89, 101, 103, 107, 109, 127, 151, 157, 163, 167, 191, 197, 199$$

We'll say an integer \$n\$ is a "Fortunate sum" if it can be expressed as the sum of two distinct Fortunate numbers. For example, \$22 = 3 + 19 = 5 + 17\$, so \$22\$ can be expressed as the sum of two Fortunate numbers, and so is a "Fortunate sum"

You are to take an integer \$n\$ as input and output a truthy value if \$n\$ is a Fortunate sum and a falsey value otherwise. You may swap the order (falsey indicates it is a Fortunate sum) if you wish. You may take input and output in any [convenient format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Test cases

The first line is the Fortunate sums less than 100 (truthy values) and the second are the integers less than or equal to 100 that aren't Fortunate sums

```
8 10 12 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 36 40 42 44 50 52 54 56 60 62 64 66 68 70 72 74 76 78 80 82 84 86 88 90 92 94 96 98
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 11 13 14 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 34 35 37 38 39 41 43 45 46 47 48 49 51 53 55 57 58 59 61 63 65 67 69 71 73 75 77 79 81 83 85 87 89 91 93 95 97 99 100
```

Comment: Brownie points for beating my 17 byte Jelly answer

Comment: One of the greatest titles I've seen on PPCG...

Comment: +1 for the musical reference

Comment: Maybe it's worth noting that we don't necessarily have \$F_j>F_i\$ for \$j>i\$. So it is most probably be incorrect to just generate fortunate numbers from \$F_1\$ to some \$F_k>n\$ and look for a valid sum using only these values. It would be interesting to have an explicit test case where this method is known to fail.

Comment: @Arnauld Interesting, I didn't notice that when generating the test cases. If such a case is found, I'll happily add it into the post (that may also invalidate my Jelly answer, but I'd have to test it with such a case to confirm)

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly The Wikipedia link shows the first Fortunate numbers as 3, 5, 7, 13, 23, 17, so _F6_ is smaller than _F5_

Comment: What may however be used to bound the search is the fact that \$F_n\$ is greater than the \$n\$-th prime.

Comment: @Arnauld `n=62` seems like such a case, it can only be formed using `3+59` and if you go in order you will encounter numbers upto 107 before getting 59. And the question already covers sums upto 100 so I think it's fine.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>130</s></sup> 128 bytes

```hs
a n=or[f x&&f(n-x)|x<-[2..n],2*x<n]
f m=or[and[p(x+y)/=(y<m)|y<-[2..m]]|x<-scanl1(*)$filter p[2..m]]
p n=all((>0).mod n)[2..n-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1LDoIwFAD3nKILQ1q0VTBxBV7BAzRdvABVwuujARYl4exW8bOemcwDpr5FjBEYVcOoLQtpajnJINZQSl0oReZQZKEkk1jmNgeo0Z6H/SKOFV9KJ9blazpjtmiqgTDnmdjZDud2ZP4HE/@eACLn15NQbmgYic9B5iY66KjyY0fzPwOmc6XOFxOftUW4T1Heihc)

This solution is based on the following observation.

**Fact.** An integer \$m>1\$ is Fortunate if and only if, for some prime number \$p_n<m\$, \$m\$ is the smallest integer \$>1\$ such that
\$
p_1 p_2\cdots p_n+m
\$
is prime.

*Proof.* The claim follows easily from the fact that if \$p_n\ge m\$ then there is some \$p_i\$ with \$i\le n\$ such that \$p_i\mid m\$, and therefore \$p_i\mid p_1 p_2\cdots p_n+m\$.

At this point, checking if a number \$m\$ is Fortunate is trivial: we just have to check the condition for all the prime numbers up to \$m\$.

### Explanation of the code

```hs
p n=all((>0).mod n)[2..n-1]
```

The standard prime-checking function. Only works for `n>1`, but that's ok.

---

```hs
f m=or[and[p(x+y)/=(y<m)|y<-[2..m]]|x<-scanl1(*)$filter p[2..m]]
```

A function to check whether a number `m` is Fortunate. As explained above, it calculates the primorials \$\texttt{x}=p_1p_2\cdots p_n\$ until \$p_n\le\texttt{m}\$ and tests whether `m` is the smallest integer \$\texttt{y}>1\$ such that \$\texttt{x}+\texttt{y}\$ is prime.

---

```hs
a n=or[f x&&f(n-x)|x<-[2..n],2*x<n]
```

The final function, to check whether `n` is a Fortunate sum. Pretty straightforward, the only thing to be careful of is that `x` and `n-x` must be different: this is the reason why we only iterate over values of `x` such that `2*x<n`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 106 bytes

```
Check[Tr[1^Union[#&@@IntegerPartitions[#,{2},Array[NextPrime[a=Times@@Array[Prime,#]+1]-a+1&,#]]]]>1,1>2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5NSxxREEX3@RWBgdl4gq/qfdVbKC1ZZRMMmFXTQiPN2MiM0LaQIPPb20KzSG3upaq49xzH9XE6juv8MG6Hq@374/Tw1N8tvdz/Ps3Pp36377ofp3U6TMvtuKzz6suXfsebnrlZlvFv/3P6s94u83Hqx6s7l5eu@zx8LNkNFzJ8Gy9k79bnWpBrHfabn0/r18vu1@s8rf3hsnszJCCKFMTQgCqa0IIaMRCVWEiBpKREDmQluymUQFFKorg3aqAqNVEL1bCAKZawghkt0JSWaIVm5@HLB0r/T/8nErwSb8BzaIjDRyQhGalIQ/0lohmtaCMKMRITMRMr0bkbSUiekklOX0lGamQhR3ImV7KRG0UokeJdldKoQo3UTK3UhgkWsYxVrNGEFmmZ5lwOFsJ52LZ3)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>14</s>  13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to ChartZBelatedly! (use the built-in for choose-2.)

Thanks to [Delfad0r](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/82619/delfad0r) for the simple explanation in their [Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220745/53748) proving that this works, I probably would not have posted it otherwise!

```
ÆRPƤ‘Æn_ƊŒc§ċ
```

A monadic Link accepting an integer \$n\$ that yields a positive integer if \$n\$ is a Fortunate Sum, or zero if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//w4ZSUMak4oCYw4ZuX8aKxZJjwqfEi////zE4)** Or see [A split of \$n\leq 100\$ into non-Fortunate and Fortunate Sums](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//w4ZSUMak4oCYw4ZuX8aKxZJjwqfEi//Dh@KCrOG5oMSg//8xMDA).

#### How?

```
ÆRPƤ‘Æn_ƊŒc§ċ - Link: integer, n                e.g. 18
ÆR            - primes between 2 and n inclusive     [2,3, 5, 7,  11,  13,   17]
   Ƥ          - for prefixes:
  P           -   product                            [2,6 ,30,210,2310,30030,510510]
        Ɗ     - last three links as a monad, f(x=that):
    ‘         - increment (x)                        [3,7 ,31,211,2311,30031,510511]
     Æn       -   next, strictly greater, prime      [5,11,37,223,2333,30047,510529]
       _      -   subtract (x)                       [3,5, 7, 13, 23,  17,   19]
         Œc   - choose-2                             [[3,5],[3,7],[3,13],[3,23],[3,17],[3,19],[5,7],[5,13],[5,23],[5,17],[5,19],[7,13],[7,23],[7,17],[7,19],[13,23],[13,17],[13,19],[23,17],[23,19],[17,19]]
           §  - sums                                 [8,10,16,26,20,22,12,18,28,22,24,20,30,24,26,36,30,32,40,42,36]
            ċ - count occurrences (of n)             1 (truthy)
```

Comment: `œc2` can be `Œc`

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks for that @ChartZBelatedly!

Comment: I lost the link to my 17 byte version, and I'm trying to remember *how* it wasn't this, because aside from me using `×\ ` instead of `PƤ` and `i` instead of `ċ`, this is exactly what I remember mine being :/

Comment: Odd, maybe you mistakenly counted what would be a footer to give either one or both of the two sets below 100?

Comment: Quite possibly. Guess we'll never know though :/ +1 for outgolfing me :)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>35</s> <s>31</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
Lʒ©ÅPηPε2®Ÿ+pJΘ}à}ãʒË_}OI¢Íd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9vc2FiaWX//0zKksKpw4VQzrdQzrUywq7FuCtwSs6YfcOgfcOjypLDi199T0nCosONZP//MTg)

-4 bytes thanks to ovs

A port of [Delfad0r](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/82619/delfad0r)'s [Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220745).

Comment: I think `OĀ` can be `à` (maximum) for -1, `Ùg<` -> `Ë_` (not all equal) and `εO}` -> `€O`.

Comment: And the `.` in `.¢` shouldn't be necessary, as we have a flat list in the end: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9vc2FiaWX//0zKksKpw4VQw4XCuyp9zrUywq7FuCtwSs6YfcOgfcOjypLDi1994oKsT0nCosONZP//MTc "05AB1E – Try It Online")